# TCP client(java) didn't receive message from TCP server(C#)

Tags: java, c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I have a GUI TCP server written in C# which listens in 4444 port and a GUI java client which connects to 4444 port. I can send message from client to server  and server side text field is set with message but when I send message from server to client no message is shown in the client's text field(also no result in console). Need help.

--Code for sending msg from server to client----- C#

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String outmsg = textBox1.Text;

        textBox1.Text = "";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(outmsg);


        String Msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
        richTextBox1.AppendText("\n\n" + Msg);


        networkStreamData.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //NetworkStream


        bytes = new byte[1024];   //For clearing the buffer



    }
```

----Java client code-----

```
 public void run () throws IOException
{
    Socket socket = new Socket ("127.0.0.1", 4444);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream ()));
    out = new PrintWriter (socket.getOutputStream (), true);

    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine ()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println ("Client <  " + inputLine);
        rxArea.setText (inputLine);
    }

    out.close();
    in.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

Note: COMMUNICATION IS WORKING FINE BETWEEN CLIENT AND SERVER, ONLY PROBLEM BETWEEN SERVER AND CLIENT.

Updates:-
I Closed the Network Stream and It worked!!! But as I have  another child thread running within the server to listen for incoming stream, so when I close the network stream it throws an exception and stop execution.

Comment: Sooo.. you get the text from the box, then append newlines to the textbox, then send the text that you read without the newlines to the client, and the client is reading with readLine()..........

Comment: Yes! But If I send Message from the Server, client isn't receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readline() needs '\n' as a message termination.As there was no termination in the sent message readline kept on reading and message wasn't set.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be closing the NetworkStream in your server code.  You then clear the buffer, which may occur before the Stream has finished sending the data.  Here is an example of creating a TCP server is C# (dotnetcore).
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/building-a-tcp-server-in-net-core-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Yes Thanks! It worked but I have a child thread running that listens for incoming message. So when I close the network stream, basically it closes the listening thread throwing 'System.IO.IOException: 'Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall.''